# Test Manager Extension says it is not installed on the organization

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

We have multiple VS Enterprise subscription users using Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) within Azure DevOps without issue.  A new user with Basic Access Level with a purchased Test Manager extension cannot create or edit existing test plans.

Within Organization Settings - Users the Test Manager extension is listed, but it has a warning symbol next to it.  The hover text states the following:

This extension is paid for or has some assignments and is not installed on the organization. Users will not have access to give extension without installation.

What do I have to do to install it on the organization?  The Test Manager extension available through Marketplace is for TFS. I assume this extension is already installed within my organization because multiple users are actively using it.

I have added and removed the Test Manager extension from the Basic user multiple times.  When I remove the extension and go to add it, it tells me that I have one license available.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can check whether the user's test permissions are set to **Allow**. e.g: the permissions in the following figure
[image]

In addition, there's a recent event that could cause this problem and we have resolved it.
You can track  this issue in this URL：https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/126800126 . If any progress, we will update this event log.

Hope this helps.